# Consuming external API using SvelteKit works but only after reloading route

Tags: fetch, endpoint, svelte-3, sveltekit

Using SvelteKit 1.0.0-next.95 to get a JSON array back from an external API endpoint and display in a template like this:

```
<script context="module">
  export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const url = 'https://www.schoolhouseyoga.com/api/announcement'
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    })

    if (res.ok) {
      return {
        props: {
          sections: await res.json()
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      status: res.status,
      error: new Error(`Could not load ${url}`)
     }
  }
</script>

<script>
  export let sections = []
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    {#if sections.length > 0}
      <div class="callout">
        <h1>Announcements</h1>
        {#each sections as section}
          <div>
            {#if section.announcements.length > 0}
              <h2>{section.section}</h2>
            {/if}
            {#each section.announcements as announcement}
              <p><b>{announcement.title} </b>- {@html announcement.description}</p>
            {/each}
          </div>
        {/each}
      </div>
    {/if}
  </section>
</template>
```

If you try https://www.schoolhouseyoga.com/api/announcement (CORS) in a browser or using curl, you'll get a JSON array with two elements.

When I run this in dev mode, `npm run dev -- --open` and navigate to this route on Safari 14.1 (macOS), I get a 500 error and the message, "Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." If I try to navigate to that route on Google Chrome, I get a 500 error and "TypeError: Failed to fetch".

But with either browser, if I refresh the page, the data loads successfully. Navigating to a different route then back again, the error reappears.

I am guessing this has to do with SSR but not sure what to do about it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to server-side rendering and a CORS issue with the endpoint. When the server-side code performed the fetch, it worked fine. Subsequent fetches were being performed by the client (which ran into the CORS issue).

While the endpoint appeared to have CORS enabled...

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import * as controller from './announcement.controller';

const router = Router();

router.get('/', cors(), controller.index);
```

But the endpoint was also using helmet and needed

```js
app.use(helmet.permittedCrossDomainPolicies());
```

prior to loading the routes.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: This does not help and is not on topic. This is for express, not Sveltekit.

Comment: In the example above, SvelteKit was calling an API on an ExpressJS server.